# New table row when maximum width is reached

Tags: html, css, tabular

I have a table with images and I would like it to make a new row when 500px is filled with cells containing images which are each 250px wide. Like word-wrap for images.
Can't make it work with max-width :/

Comment: Why do you need that table? If the table is necessary, you will have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a table. Tables are only meant to be used to display tabular data. Best to just use divs.

```
.wrapper {
 width:500px;
 overflow:auto;
}
.wrapper img {
 width:250px;
 float:left;
}


<div class="wrapper">

    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the default behavior of images in a block element? (like div or p) why do you need a table for?

You can also make a table cell that spans all the columns and insert images into it. When the max width is reached, they will wrap.